# calling a model inside a model with tensorflow : layers do not support float type inputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras

for learning i tried to  to use tensorflow probability to fit a simple 1 dimensional function (x,y) but i have realized i do something wrong when i call a model inside another model and i really need to understand what.

here is my model

```
mlp1 = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1), dtype=tf.float32),
        Dense(20, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
        Dense(20, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
        Dense(1, activation="softplus",name="layer3"),
    ]
)


class subq0(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mlp1=mlp1()



    def call(self, inputs):
        sigma= self.mlp1(inputs)

        return sigma



polynom = subq0()
optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.0001,momentum=0.9)
polynom.compile(optimizer=optimizer,  loss= "mse"  ) 
polynom.build(input_shape=(1,))
polynom.summary()



polynomial.fit(X_train, y_train , epochs= 100, verbose=0, batch_size=64 ,validation_data=(X_val,y_val) )
```

the error i get is

> ValueError: You cannot build your model by calling `build` if your
> layers do not support float type inputs. Instead, in order to
> instantiate and build your model, call your model on real tensor data
> (of the correct dtype).
>
> The actual error from `call` is:
> 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object is not callable.

Comment: What is mlp1(tf.ones(1)) supposed to do?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy   ah sorry , forgot to remove it. i was trying to see if mlp1 worked., i will remove it.

Comment: Same question now for mlp1(), do you still get the same error? because now the code should just not work.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy. no it throws another error "ValueError: The first argument to `Layer.call` must always be passed.

Comment: Of course, you are calling a model without any input, now you should try to answer my question, what is that line of code doing?

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy well i pass the inputs with `polynomial.fit(X_train, y_train , epochs= 100, verbose=0, batch_size=64 ,validation_data=(X_val,y_val) )  `  i wanted to fit a function

Comment: You have a model already, why are you embedding it in another model? You can just do self.mp1 = tf.keras.Sequential(....) inside the _ _ init _ _ of your second model.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy i found it easier to read. shouldn't it work in the same way? i tried , it   raise "TypeError: 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor' object is not callable" now.

Comment: That you get errors should tell you it does not work the same way.